# Как рассчитать вероятность победы для трёх и более участников соревнования (желательно на Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

К примеру проходит некое состязание в котором участвуют четыре участника со следующими шансами на победу: первый - 20, второй - 40, третий - 60, четвертый - 70. Т.е. шанс на победу, это произвольное число, некий показатель силы. Состязание проходит в несколько раундов, победитель в каждом раунде может быть только один. Как произвести расчет количества побед за несколько раундов, к примеру 10, для каждого игрока, с учётом его шансов на победу?

Comment: Что именно означают эти числа?

Comment: а какой пральный ответ ? 4,3,2,1 ?

Comment: Пусть вероятность победы игрока равна p, тогда мат. ожидание числа побед после n раундов будет равно n * p. Вы не объяснили, как именно найти вероятность победы игрока, исходя из ваших чисел, но предположим, что победы распределяются пропорционально их силе, тогда p1 = 20 / (20 + 40 + 60 + 70) ~= 0.105, и он победит 0.105 * 10 = 1.05 раз за десять раундов.

Answer (score 1):

Ну это получается "метод Монте-Карло" видимо. Только раундов пришлось взять побольше, иначе у игроков с маленькими шансами вообще ни разу побед не бывает:

```
import random
from collections import Counter

num_players = 4
player_numbers = list(range(1,num_players+1))
player_chances = dict(zip(player_numbers, [20,40,60,70]))
rounds = 100

c = Counter(max(player_numbers, key=lambda x: random.random() * player_chances[x]) for _ in range(rounds))
print(c.most_common())
```

Вывод (игрок, побед):

```
[(4, 45), (3, 43), (2, 11), (1, 1)]
```